# image carousel auto resize

Tags: css, wordpress, carousel

I have a page consisting of 3 rows with 2 columns, each containing an image carousel & a section of text. My problem is I can't figure out how to make the carousels fit the column automatically (i tried width/height:auto/100%) but there's always blank space to the side or the bottom or both. It'd be okay if some of the images get cropped out when it adjusts to fit, it's just annoying that when I use the computer at the office there's more blank space because the monitor is wider. What can i do?

Comment: I recommend you to embed sample code on your question and what carousel plugin are you using. Otherwise is hard to detect exactly what's happening.

Comment: Please add some code or a JS Fiddle: www.jsfiddle.net